# Fire event programmatically C#

Tags: c#, events

I have several radio buttons inside a container. For each one I have the `CheckedChanged`event so I have a code like this

```cs
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    // do stuff...
}
private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    // do stuff...
}
private void radioButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((sender as RadioButton).Checked)
    // do stuff...
}
// ... and so on...
```

Then I must fire the `CheckedChanged` event for the currently checked `radioButton`. To get the `radioButton` I used this code:

```cs
RadioButton checkedButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>()
                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
```

Now how can I fire the `CheckedChanged` event for `checkedButton`?

EDIT: I'm using WinForms. My radio buttons are in a `tabPage`. When I open the `tabPage` I need to know what is the currently checked `radioButton` and fire the corresponding `checkedChanged` event. This is because when I select another `tabPage` I perform other actions and, going back to the `tabPage` containing the radio buttons, I need to restore the previous state.

Comment: Is this WPF, web forms, what?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . Why do you need to fire the event? Wasn't the event fired when the user clicked the radio button?

Comment: I usually have the change event call helper method to do all the work.  Then if I need to execute the same code I simply call the helper method and not have to execute the event.

Comment: The direct answer is: You can't. Events provide strong encapsulation and the Control classes usually don't provide a public method for raising an event. Because you shouldn't need it.

Comment: @bommelding In WPF you certainly can. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.raiseevent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The container is in a tabControl, when I open the tab I need to know what is the checked radioButton and fire the corresponding event.

Comment: `The container is in a tabControl, when I open the tab I need to know what is the checked radioButton and fire the corresponding event.` Extract your existing `CheckedChanged` event logic into a new function. Let's call it `Bob`. When the tab is clicked, call the `Bob` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the value of the `Checked` property should fire the event:

```
checkedButton .Checked = !checkedButton .Checked;
```

You may also call the event handler explicitly, e.g.:

```
RadioButton checkedButton = container.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
switch (checkedButton.Name)
{
    case "radioButton1":
        radioButton1_CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        break;
    case "radioButton2":
        radioButton2_CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        break;
    case "radioButton3":
        radioButton3_CheckedChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        break;
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you may of course want to consider using the same event handler for all `RadioButtons`.